# ¿Cómo asigno el valor de una variable que está dentro de una función a una que está fuera?

Tags: javascript, variables

Tengo esa función de *Javascript* que se ejecuta con un botón y necesito que el valor de `acum1` lo pueda asignar a la variable que está fuera que se llama **mi variable**. (Lo que pondría es un `string`).

```
function capturar()
{   
    // Obtenemos el valor por el id
    var porId=document.getElementById("mycolor").value;
    acum= acum + '"'+ porId +'"' + ",";
    acum1 = acum;
    acum1 = acum1.substring(0,acum1.length-1);
}
var mivariable = acum1;
```

Answer (score 2):

debes definir tu variable que se encuentra afuera mucho antes de usar la función, así, cuando te encuentres en el contexto de la función puedas acceder a ese espacio y asignar el valor que obtienes dentro de la funcion

```js
var mivariable;
function capturar()
{   
    // Obtenemos el valor por el id
    var porId=document.getElementById("mycolor").value;
    acum= acum + '"'+ porId +'"' + ",";
    acum1 = acum;
    acum1 = acum1.substring(0,acum1.length-1);
    mivariable = acum1;
}
```

Comment: amigo muchas gracias por tu respuesta.. se me olvidó especificar que mi variable es de tipo arreglo: 

básicamente acum1 lo que tiene es un String con "hola", "estoy", "programando" y a ese string lo quiero poner en la variable  algo así mivariable = [acum1], 

para que así mivariable sea algo como mivariable = ["hola", "estoy", "programando"]

Answer (score 0):

Probé esta solución y la respuesta fue undefined

```
var mivariable;
function capturar()
    {   
        // Obtenemos el valor por el id
        var porId=document.getElementById("mycolor").value;
        acum= acum + '"'+ porId +'"' + ",";
        acum1 = acum;
        acum1 = acum1.substring(0,acum1.length-1);
        mivariable = acum1;
    }

alert(mivariable);
```

Comment: Es el error normal ya que **Jamás se hace el llamado a la función** y por lo tanto no tiene valor la variable. Para resolver antes del alert llame  a su función `capturar()`